# Unable to locate package ros-cturtle-pr2

Tags: pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All.
While I try to develop the demo of following website, I meet a problem in the first step.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/SimpleGraspingDemo
sudo apt-get install ros-cturtle-pr2all
Then I got the following information:
administrator@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-cturtle-pr2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-cturtle-pr2

I am using ubuntu 11.04.64 bit electric ros.
I install the
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-pr2-desktop
and
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full
That is no problem.
IS there some change of the package?
How to develop this demo in PR2 simulator?
Best regards.
Zhenli

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27693/unable-to-locate-package-ros-cturtle-pr2/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I don't think there is a "pr2all" package in electric. "ros-cturtle-pr2all" means you are looking for a cturtle package but actually you are using electric.

Maybe you can try installing the ros-electric-pr2-tabletop-manipulation-apps package and follow these tutorials: http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_pick_and_place.

Best,
Juergen

---

Originally posted by [JuergenHess](https://answers.ros.org/users/370/juergenhess/) with karma: 86 on 2012-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-04-08**:
Hi,
I am having the same problem, but my system is ros groovy. is there any package for pr2 pick and place demo?
Thanks